# Python Regex - checking for a capital letter with a lowercase after

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to check for a capital letter that has a lowercase letter coming directly after it. The trick is that there is going to be a bunch of garbage capital letters and number coming directly before it. For example:

```
AASKH317298DIUANFProgramming is fun
```

as you can see, there is a bunch of stuff we don't need coming directly before the phrase we do need, `Programming is fun`.

I am trying to use regex to do this by taking each string and then substituting it out with `''` as the original string does not have to be kept.

```
re.sub(r'^[A-Z0-9]*', '', string)
```

The problem with this code is that it leaves us with `rogramming is fun`, as the `P` is a capital letter.

How would I go about checking to make sure that if the next letter is a lowercase, then I should leave that capital untouched. (The `P` in `Programming`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a negative look-ahead:

```
re.sub(r'^[A-Z0-9]*(?![a-z])', '', string)
```

This matches any uppercase character or digit that is *not* followed by a lowercase character.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'AASKH317298DIUANFProgramming is fun'
>>> re.sub(r'^[A-Z0-9]*(?![a-z])', '', string)
'Programming is fun'
```

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: @user2909227: a look-around assertion matches a *location*; a look-ahead assertion matches any spot that is followed by the look-ahead pattern. A negative look-ahead matches spots the look-ahead pattern is *not* present. Same for look-behinds, but for spots preceded by the pattern.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly!

Comment: @user2909227: so `(?![a-z])` makes `P` *not* match because there is a lowercase letter right after it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is this better than using `re.findall` on `[A-Z][a-z ]+`?

Comment: @adsmith: that depends on the real-world data; sometimes the pattern for the prefix is cleaner, sometimes matching everything *but* the prefix is.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use match like this :

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'AASKH317298DIUANFProgramming is fun'
>>> r = r'^.*([A-Z][a-z].*)$'
>>> m = re.match(r, s)
>>> if m:
...     print(m.group(1))
... 
Programming is fun
```