# regex carry look behind ip adress

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

Is there a regex, which will read and return the ip address in proper format in this text? Note it's backward, so the regex would have to step through the code backwards then replace '|' with '.'

It's been driving me crazy... and I'd appreciate your help ;)

**Excerpt From Code:**

> 4.3/d/c/b.a",10:"0://8.7/1/1.f",z:"0://8.7/1/y.x",w:"0://6.5.4.3/i/v/u.t",s:"r",q:p,o:n,9:\'0\',m:[{2:"l",k:"0://8.7/1/1.f"},{2:"j",h:{e:\'0://6.5.4.3/d/c/b.a\',\'9\':\'0\'}},{2:"g"}]});',36,40,'|type|187|20|207|31|com|hystorystingbulk|

**Desired Return:**

> 31.207.20.187

Thanks!

Edit: I have bits and pieces, but I can't put it together to get me the desired outcome

> (?<=/|^) -- a positive lookbehind
>
> \b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b -- this will get you the ip in
>   a given file/text
>
> \b\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}\|\d{1,3}\b --this returns the ip (but
>   backwards. remember I wanted it flipped) and separated by '|' instead
>   of '.'

Someone asked....I'm using Python and testing using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html THX

Comment: Could you post the code you already tried? This is not a 'we will write your code for free'-site.

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to specify which regex engine (or at least, which language) you're using. There are so many differences between PCRE and POXIX extended regexes, for example.

Comment: There's nothing *simple* about regexes, that's for sure: why not download python and use it locally? Or look for an online full-blown interpreter? Why must you use this site in particular?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way is to store each number individually into a group, then format and join the groups together later.

Some such:

`/(\d+)\|(\d+)\|(\d+)|(\d+)/`

That creates 5 different match groups, one for each set of parents `( )` and one around the whole match. But this ain't Perl! Now, in Python that would have to be more like

`match("(\\d+)\\|(\\d+)\\|(\\d+)|(\\d+)", ..)`

Then, use `group` to grab out the individual matches and put them together in the right order:

`group(...) "." group(...) "." group(...) "." group(...)`

Tada!

Disclaimer: This is not really Pythonic syntax, but should give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an option I have :(

Comment: I don't think there really is another option. What are you using? `sed`??

Comment: It's certainly possibly in Python, with match and groups.

Comment: I just need to piece those (see my edits together) :(

Comment: Here's an answer from today that uses match groups, in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21805543/712526

Comment: Thanks jpaugh....but no can do :( I need simple expression like those mentioned in my edits.

Comment: Well... no *can* do, then! :-)

Comment: Unles you find some way to wrap it in a lambda. Syntactically, they *are* expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
expression = re.compile("(\d{1,3})\|(\d{1,3})\|(\d{1,3})\|(\d{1,3})")
text = """4.3/d/c/b.a",10:"0://8.7/1/1.f",z:"0://8.7/1/y.x",w:"0://6.5.4.3/i/v/u.t",s:"r",q:p,o:n,9:\'0\',m:[{2:"l",k:"0://8.7/1/1.f"},{2:"j",h:{e:\'0://6.5.4.3/d/c/b.a\',\'9\':\'0\'}},{2:"g"}]});',36,40,'|type|187|20|207|31|com|hystorystingbulk|"""

matches = expression.findall(text)

IPs = ['.'.join(reversed(match)) for match in matches]

>>> print(IPs)
['31.207.20.187']
```